# how do i resolve this simple for loop issue, im stumped on this type error issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
cost = [1.25, 3.00, 2.00, 4.75]
items = ["chocolate bar", "cone", "medium float", "ice cream sunday"]

print("Cost  -  Product")

i=0

for i in range(len(cost)):
    print(cost[i] + " - " + items[i])
```

When I run this, something in my for loop breaks, I have tried to understand this and have failed, I'm a beginner and I was assigned the task of putting together something with the 'for loop' This i supposed to be a simple question so I was wondering if someone could explain why it fails and what  is best practice for something such as this.

my output ::

```html
Cost  -  Product
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(cost[i] + " - " + items[i])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

```

Thanks to all for any help!

Comment: You don't need `i=0`, i is representing the elements in the list created by `range(len(cost))` not a variable being incremented.

Answer (score 1):

The Interpreter doesn't automatically convert numbers to strings when mixing those types using the `+` operator. Add `str()` to your numbers to cast them to strings.

```
cost = [1.25, 3.00, 2.00, 4.75]
items = ["chocolate bar", "cone", "medium float", "ice cream sunday"]

print("Cost  -  Product")

for i in range(len(cost)):
    print(str(cost[i]) + " - " + str(items[i]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only [`concatenate`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-concatenation/) strings to strings. `cost[i]` will give you a float, and you are trying to concatenate that with `"="` which is a string.

The best way to concatenate would be to use [`f-strings`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/)

```
cost = [1.25, 3.00, 2.00, 4.75]
items = ["chocolate bar", "cone", "medium float", "ice cream sunday"]
print("Cost  -  Product")
i=0
for i in range(len(cost)):
    print(f"{cost[i]}   -  {items[i]}")
```

Lastly, your loop can be replaced with `for x,y in zip(xx,yy)`

```
for price,item in zip(cost,items):
    print(f"{price}   -  {item}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving an error message because your code tries to use `+` operand with real number and string.

1. Change `print(cost[i] + " - " + items[i])` to `print(str(cost[i]) + " - " + items[i])` - *Here you firstly convert real number to string and then concatenate two strings*
2. Replace `print(cost[i] + " - " + items[i])` with `print(f"{cost[i]} - {items[i]}")`. *This is called string formatting and it will automatically convert variables to strings.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension

```
cost = [1.25, 3.00, 2.00, 4.75]
items = ["chocolate bar", "cone", "medium float", "ice cream sunday"]
print("Cost  -  Product")
[print(f"{cost[i]} - {items[i]}") for i in range(len(cost))]
```